# Aitoff projections using healpy and projplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, healpy

I have a range of theta and phi’s using the healpy  pix2ang command, 
and then transforming to RA, Decl.::

```
ra = np.rad2deg(phi)
dec = np.rad2deg(0.5 * np.pi - theta)
```

I just want to project these onto an e.g. Aitoff type projection, but for the life of me can’t figure out how to do this via:: 
    https://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/healpy.visufunc.projplot.html

```
projplot(ra, dec, 'bo')
```

doesn't really do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hp.projplot` is used to add lines to *an existing plot*. If you're just interested in plotting lines on a different projection, I recommend you check out [matplotlib's projections](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/geo_demo.html).

For healpy, please find a quick example below.

```
import healpy as hp
import numpy as np

nside = 64
npix = hp.nside2npix(nside)
arr = np.random.randn(npix)

# Draw a circle
r = np.full(100, 20.)
phi = np.linspace(0., 2*np.pi, 100)
x = np.cos(phi)*r
y = np.sin(phi)*r

# Plot the map and the circle
hp.mollview(arr)
hp.projplot(x, y, c='r', lonlat=True)
```

[image]